# Proper usage of "take your time"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

What is the proper usage of "take your time"? Can we use it in the following context?

> Rachel sent me an email saying that she is busy and will not be able to meet me until the following week.

In a reply to her, can I use "take your time"?

> That's fine. **Take your time.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't quite right. "Take your time" normally applies to completion of some task or duty rather than to non-specific delays.

Comment: So what could be a better alternative?

Comment: You can just use an unadorned "That's fine." Or append "Whenever you can," or "It's not (terribly) urgent." Just about anything will do.

Comment: Another common response would be "No rush"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can — provided you are sure she will understand it.

Comment: How could I make sure that she will understand it? Is there a better version, probably more clearer and natural?

Comment: @Noah: It depends on how well you know her. An alternative might be 'There's no hurry.'